# Why is MySQL View table with UNIONS way slower than ordinary SQL statements with UNIONS?

Tags: mysql, union, sql-view

Can someone explain why this query is faster

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table_1
  UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table_2
  UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table_3;
```

than creating a view from this mysql statement?

```
CREATE VIEW test_table_x AS    
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table_2
    UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table_3;
```

Tables table_1, table_2, and table_3 have 5000 records each and when I query the above SQL, the running time is around `0.0050` seconds while querying `SELECT * FROM test_table_x;` takes about `0.107` seconds.

**EDIT**

Added the EXPLAIN in MySQL
Result for the SQL query

```
EXPLAIN
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table_2
    UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table_3;
```

[image]

Result for the SQL Query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM test_table_x;
```

[image]

Comment: What is the execution plan for both queries ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha what do you mean execution plan?

Comment: Run explain before both queries. `explain SELECT * FROM my_test_view;`

Comment: @ErgestBasha okay, let me do that, these tables are just arbitrary as my t1, t2, and t3 are tables with more than 20 columns. Let me run throught the EXPLAIN SQL first.

Comment: Looks like the query returns the output immediately whereas the view materializes it to disk. Investigate profiles for both queries (SHOW PROFILE).

Comment: @ErgestBasha I added the results for the EXPLAIN in both of the SQLs.